# Using different database in NTICompass CodeIgniter Subqueries

Tags: codeigniter, subquery

Pardon for my beginner in object oriented PHP Codeigniter. I am confused about using `$this->subquery->defaultDB()` in https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries?

```
$db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);

$this->load->library('Subquery');
$this->subquery->defaultDB($db2)
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('select');
$sub->select('number')->from('numbers')->where('numberID', 2);
$this->subquery->end_subquery('number');

$query = $db2->get('mytable');
```

but the subquery still use the default database not db2. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created [issue](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/issues/7) to its repository and the author said he will fix it on a few days.

If you are in a rush using this code, I have an alternative. I add forth param `defaultDB` to be used in subquery. Hope it helps. Cheers!

```
function start_subquery($statement, $join_type='', $join_on=1, $defaultDB=''){
    $db = $this->CI->load->database($defaultDB, true);
    $this->dbStack[] = $db;
    $this->statement[] = $statement;
    if(strtolower($statement) == 'join'){
        $this->join_type[] = $join_type;
        $this->join_on[] = $join_on;
    }
    return $db;
}
```